# R ggplot2 - Simple plot- cannot specify log axis limits

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

I'm trying to create a simple densityplot in R in ggplot2. Here's my code which works great.

```
d <-  ggplot(result, aes(x=result$baseMeanA)) 
d + geom_density(colour="darkgreen", size=2, fill="darkgreen") + 
scale_x_log10() + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.45))
```

The problem is that I cannot adjust the x-axis as I would like, into negative numbers.

```
scale_x_log10(limits= c(1, 10000))
```

works great, but

```
scale_x_log10(limits= c(-1, 10000))
```

does not work at all! It gives me this error:

> Error in if (zero_range(range)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Please help!

Comment: Just guessing, but perhaps you want the limits on the original scale to go from 0.1 to 10000 (i.e. log10(x) goes from -1 to 5) ?  Presumably you don't want log10(x) to go from -1 to 10000, because the upper limit would then be at 10^10000 (a *very* large value, since there are about 10^80 atoms in the observable universe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe ... ) If I'm right, then you want `scale_x_log10(limits=c(0.1,1e5))`

Comment: Yes I think I understand now. I can't  use negative numbers in a log scale.. Thank you. I see now what I need to do, I need to add a pseudonumber like 1 or 0.1 to the result, so that it visually will look correct, otherwise I will loose all the very small numbers somehow.

Answer (score 5):

If the range of the limits should be partly below zero, you could log10-transform your variable and specify the limits for a continuous scale:

```
ggplot(result, aes(x=log10(baseMeanA))) +
   geom_density(colour="darkgreen", size=2, fill="darkgreen") + 
   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1, 10000) + 
   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.45)) +
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do doesn't make much sense does it? The log of negative numbers isn't something we can represent in R

```
R> log(-1)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In log(-1) : NaNs produced
```

so where should R draw the axis to?

Comment: Yes, you are right probably. I did not know that. I think I know now that to solve my problem I need to add a pseudonumber to my result so that I visually can look at it.

Answer (score 1):

e^y cannot be negative.  The exponential constant e is positive, and y is just an exponent.  and by mathematical definition:

log(x) = y    <==>    x = e^y

This is precisely why R cannot calculate log(x) if x is negative.  It just goes against the math definition.

I hope this helps understanding why this plot is giving you trouble.